# How do I make the sorted function ignore some characters?

Tags: python, sorting

I'm pretty new to python and was sorting through an array of strings. But I noticed a problem for my use case.

Take an array like the following:

`["C", "CSS", "CSA", "C-SHARP"]`

When I pass it through `sorted()`, it becomes:

`["C-SHARP", "C", "CSA", "CSS"]`

Is there a way I can ignore some characters, which for my case is the `'-'` character, so that the result becomes:

`["C", "CSA", "C-SHARP", "CSS"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort using a lambda which removes non alphanumeric characters:

```
inp = ["C", "CSS", "CSA", "C-SHARP"]
out = sorted(inp, key=lambda x: re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', x))
print(out)
```

This prints:

```
['C', 'CSA', 'C-SHARP', 'CSS']
```

Comment: Yes, this works like a charm! But I was wondering, does the regex refer to the '-' character, or is it something else?

Comment: @ChrisGeorge do you just want to remove this character '-' ?

Comment: @HozayfaElRifai Yeah I just wanted to replace '-' for my case, but I was wondering how to do it for other characters, and realized that the regex is for the character(s) to be replaced.

Comment: @ChrisGeorge this approach is the best, you may need to consider deleting 0-9 too.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `"-"` with `""` while sorting. This won't affect the final list.

```
sorted(your_list, key=lambda item: item.replace("-", ""))
```

Result

```
['C', 'CSA', 'C-SHARP', 'CSS']
```